# Using Travis.ci with R

Tags: r, travis-ci

I wanted to use the Travis.ci service to test my R package.
I created the .travis.yml file like described [Here](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/blob/master/sample.travis.yml)

I don´t want to use testthat cases for my package at the moment. I just want to make the travis service check if the package can be installed with the devtools from github.

My travis.yml file:

```
 language: c

before_install:
  - cd ThinkToStartR
  - curl -OL http://raw.github.com/craigcitro/r-travis/master/scripts/travis-tool.sh
  - chmod 755 ./travis-tool.sh
  - ./travis-tool.sh bootstrap

install:
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_deps

script: ./travis-tool.sh run_tests

after_failure:
  - ./travis-tool.sh dump_logs

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: change
    on_failure: change
```

But when travis starts to works it gives me the error:

> The command "./travis-tool.sh run_tests" exited with 1.

How can I get travis to install my package?

Package: https://github.com/JulianHill/ThinkToStartR

Comment: Your directory https://github.com/JulianHill/ThinkToStartR is not in the form of an R package the subdirectory https://github.com/JulianHill/ThinkToStartR/tree/master/ThinkToStartR is however. The error arises as travis (R) tries to build a package from the main directory rather then the subdirectory which contains your package.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I make Travis to build the package from the subdirectory?

Comment: This post may help http://www.rochester.edu/college/gradstudents/jolmsted/blog/2014/01/05/r-pkgs-on-travis/ . So basically just tweak your `travis.yml` so that it cd's to the sub directory.

Comment: But I used cd ThinkToStartR in my travis file. So it should execute in the subdirectory or?

Comment: Should the `cd` not be in the `install` section?

Comment: No as travis is just like a console. So when I use cd ThinkToStartR it stays in that directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in this case is not with travis. Your R code doesnt pass check. In `instant_pkgs.r` there are calls to `install.packages`. A `repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org"` needs to be added to the two instances of these functions. This solves the initial problem. You have a dummy manual page `ThinkToStart-package.Rd` with

```
\examples{
~~ simple examples of the most important functions ~~
}
```

changing this to

```
\examples{
}
```

now allows the package to pass check.

The changes can be viewed https://github.com/johndharrison/ThinkToStartR/blob/master/ThinkToStartR/R/instant_pkgs.r and https://github.com/johndharrison/ThinkToStartR/blob/master/ThinkToStartR/man/ThinkToStart-package.Rd the resulting travis pass can be viewed https://travis-ci.org/johndharrison/ThinkToStartR